# is it possible to addEventSource using googleCalendarId?

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

In "FullCalendar" I could add an event using "addEventSource" by array manually, however, I could not succeed adding the event through Google Calendar ID.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource",{
    events:  [
      {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2019-02-01'
      }
    ]
  });
```

THE BELOW SNIPPET NOT GETTING THROUGH. PLS ASSIST

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource",{
    events:  {
      googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com',
    }
  });
```

FYI by FUllcalendar: Source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option. Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly please ensure you followed all the steps in the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) beforehand otherwise it won't work.

Secondly, your object structure is wrong. The `events` wrapper should not be there when specifying an event source. Perhaps you confused the `events` option in fullCalendar as being part of the structure required for an event source object, which is documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object

Specifically it documents the structure for a google calendar to be the source:

```
{
  googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com',
  color: 'yellow',   // an option!
  textColor: 'black' // an option!
}
```

So I suggest you change your code as follows, to match the documented object structure. Basically you just remove the erroneous `events` bit:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource", {
  googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com',
});
```